# How do you prove the particle went through both slits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, interference

I'm only a casual reader so maybe i misunderstood something so far but here is my current understanding:

The pattern we see from the 2 slit experiment emerges due to two probability waves, one emerging from each slit causing interference with each other (constructive or destructive), even though the two waves are from the same particle.

Which means at least mathematically and making the assumption a particle goes through both slits, we can explain the pattern. But its this assumption made that i don't fully grasp.

How do you physically prove that it went through both slits?

Or is this more of a situation of "well the math works so do you have any better suggestions"?

Comment: It's pretty strsightforward.  Block either slit and the interference pattern goes away, even if there's only one "particle" in the apparatus at a time and the pattern is built up from many separate detections.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if that really counts as proof, but rather a good assumption at most, because you've now changed the setup, you've got more particles added to the slit wall by adding the block mass on one slit, and only one path through which would surely change the way a particle propagates when near the wall anyway such as EM force distribution of the wall?

Comment: Also adding a block to the slit would also add mass to the system and change the gravitational field lines, so that would also affect the particle even if negligible - so its surely not right to say it's the same setup so can make conclusions of the two slit setup and use that as proof?

Comment: This question has been debated since the beginning of quantum mechanics. Physical interpretation of quantum mechanics is quite a challenge. It's mostly along the lines "it works incredibly well as a predictive theory but no one has a clue how and why it works". Good read for starters would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics

Comment: Ah so the idea of it going through both slits is not a physical description. It seems quite a lot of reading material fails to mention that and has kind've taken it literally which is what threw me off.

Comment: The idea of the wave function going through both slits *is* a physical description, even though the wave function itself (for a single particle) cannot be physically measured.

Comment: I thought the wave was a probability wave as I've heard mention more so than it actually being the physical particle energy which we do not know about since we cannot measure it?

Comment: @WDUK, If changing the mass of the beam blocker affected the outcome, you might be right that gravity plays a role.  But it doesn't.  Bringing a slug of depleted uranium near one of the slits (without actually blocking the slit) won't affect the outcome, either.

Comment: @WDUK, it can be argued that individual particles go through only one slit.  And it can be demonstrated experimentally that a huge number of particles in the double slit experiment distribute themselves such that they produce an "interference pattern" on a screen behind the slits.  The "interference distribution" of those particles that implies that they went through both slits is a statistical thing which doesn't apply to each individual particle, because statistics applies to a large collection of particles rather than to a single particle.

Comment: @DavidWhite oh i see, so the the description is based on explaining the distribution of many particles rather than what a single particle might have done, for which we don't know much about an individual particle's journey?

Comment: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html one classic to read. Yet, it seems lacking something on this issue....

Comment: Some explanation to your question [is this more of a situation of "well the math works so do you have any better suggestions"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/635220/the-double-slit-experiment-with-electrons)